# Webpack Karma using react/addons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I have a large-ish Angular app written in Typescript generating JS files 1:1 plus external modules such as moment and React loaded off the same server. Dependencies are handled by RequireJS.

We added some basic Angular Karma tests which worked fine. This uses a duplicate RequireJS config tweaked to load the tests into Karma.

Now I am trying to test some React components and in the process move to Webpack. So, I have modified the Karma config to use Webpack and installed the external dependencies using npm. I have spent all day trying to get this to work but I cannot find a solution which works for my setup.

**karma.conf.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'ng/*.js',
            'ng/**/*.js',
            'ng/**/tests/*.spec.js'


        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
                'app.js', // Old requirejs config
           ],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            '*.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
            'ng/**/*.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
            'partials/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
        },


   webpack: { //kind of a copy of your webpack config
      devtool: 'inline-source-map', //just do inline source maps instead of the default
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            query: {
              presets: ['airbnb']
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json',
          },
          {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'typescript',
          },
        ],
      },

      externals: {
        'react': true,
        'react/addons': true,
        'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
        'react/lib/ReactContext': true
      }
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true //please don't spam the console when running in karma!
    },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['PhantomJS',
                   'Chrome'
                ],

        plugins: [
             'karma-webpack',
             'karma-sourcemap-loader',
             'karma-requirejs',
             'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',

             //'karma-firefox-launcher',
             'karma-chrome-launcher',
             'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
             'karma-jasmine'
        ],

    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        presets: ['airbnb']
      }
    },

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultanous
        concurrency: Infinity,

    });
};
```

This is what I am getting:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: react
  at /vagrant/app/media/website/js/ng/chartApp.js:48060 <- webpack:/external "react/addons":1:0
```

How should I be setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening if you're using Enzyme, which uses some lazy `require()` calls to maintain compatibility with React 0.13 and 0.14, so Webpack isn't bundling them.

If that's the case, put this in your `karma.config.js`:

`webpack: {
    // ...whatever else you have...
    externals: {
      'cheerio': 'window',
      'react/addons': true,
      'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
      'react/lib/ReactContext': true
    }
  }`

If you're not using Enzyme, this might still be a solution (at least the `react/addons` part).

See [this Karma page](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/karma.md) for details.

Answer (score -2):

Here's your first problem:

"I have a large-ish **Angular** app written in **Typescript** generating JS files 1:1 **plus external modules** such as **moment** and **React** loaded off the same server. Dependencies are handled by **RequireJS**."

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: It's also a diagnosis